# How do I create an instance of a parent class from a Generic type, and then use it to call a child class method?

Tags: java, class, generics

I'm writing my program and I am trying to run a method from a specific class based on a String you give to the program. I am aware of `Class.forName()`, however my classes aren't located in the same package and it just makes it a huge mess to deal with, since I am looking to optimize my code I would rather not do that. Instead, I wrote a custom ClassLoader, which I can use to load all of the classes that I want at once. These classes all have one parent class, which has the methods I need to use, and the children of those classes all override the parent functions. I would to be able to input the name of the child class, and then run its corresponding `run()` method, if possible, without doing a lot of type checks (I have about 20 different child classes). Here's my code so far:

```
content = content.substring(prefix.length());
        
OweoClassLoader ocl = new OweoClassLoader();
String[] blacklist = {"Command", "ToggleableCommand", "NonToggleableCommand"};

//The array of child classes I want to use
ArrayList<Class<?>> commandClasses = ocl.getClasses(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/bin/io/github/epicoweo/commands", blacklist);

//Just capitalizing the first letter of the input string
char[] command = content.split("\\s+")[0].toCharArray();
String str = "";
str += Character.toString(command[0]).toUpperCase();
if(command.length > 1) {
    for(int i = 1; i < command.length; i++) {
        str += command[i];
    }
}

for(Class<?> c : commandClasses) {
    if(Command.class.isAssignableFrom(c)) { //Command is the parent class, which also has a run method
        //right here I want to be able to call
        c.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance().run(); //the child class's run method, not the parent's
    }
}
```

Is this possible without making a giant switch case tower? Thanks!

Comment: You should probably be using [SPI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/spi.html).

Comment: As I was reading this question — *before I even got down to the comments* — I was thinking to myself: „*Does dude realize he's reinventing the JDK's built-in Service Provider mechanism?*“. And then I read @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-'s comment, which is right on the money. Do yourself a favor and read that document at the link s/he shared.

Comment: @deduper, I think that looks like a good idea. Reading the docs though, I don't really see how I could implement that. Could you please point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: And, if I'm gonna be 100% honest, the docs and most things I can find online are confusing the hell out of me, I tried to make a Hello World service to get started with it, and it threw a `java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: provider is not a subtype`, even though my provider implements my service class. Any ideas?

Comment: See [*Spring's take on Service Loader*](https://blog.frankel.ch/java-service-loader-vs-spring-factories/). I prefer that way myself. Hella easier. But it's still Service Loader. [*Another one I had bookmarked*](https://dzone.com/articles/extensible-libraries-with-serviceloader-and-spring). That [*linked to this one*](https://dzone.com/articles/play-with-java-serviceloader-forget-about-dependen?fromrel=true) which looks more complete. Also search *baeldung.com* to see if they have a Service Loader guide. Either way, try rereading the Oracle one at some point. It will start to click eventually.

Comment: @deduper Okay, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Baeldung's guides are usually not too much work to follow: [*Java Service Provider Interface*](https://www.baeldung.com/java-spi).